# Content Was Overlaid with Smaller Size Browser

Tags: html, css

Why introduction text was overlaid by the profile image when the browser was scaled down to 650px? They suppose to show in 100% width at 650px screen. I did adjust the position of .speakers-info from absolute to relative, it seems solved the overlay problem but then all position setting got messed. Please see the code as below and advise how to solve it, thank you!

[Screenshot: the introduction text was overlaid by the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vs1A.png)

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

#middle-2 {
width: auto;
color: #000;
margin: 5% 10%;
display: inline-block;
}

.speakers-1{
  margin: 8% 0;
}

.speakers-text {
  padding: 0 5% 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.speakers-info {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  padding: 0 5% 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.speakers-image {
  height: 130px;
  margin: -66px 0 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

[class*="col-"]{
  float: left;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}


<section id="middle-2">
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="speakers-1">
            <h2>Aaron Irizarry</h2>
            <h3>DESIGNING A CULTURE OF DESIGN</h3>

            <div class="speakers-info col-3 col-s-12">
                <img class="speakers-image" src="https://jolly-kalam.jpg" alt="pic: aaron-irizarry">
                <p><a href="twitter.com/#">@aaroni</a><br><a href="disdesign.com">discussingdesign.com</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="speakers-text col-7 col-s-12">
                <p>Workplace culture doesn’t start with beanbags, foosball tables, or a beer fridge, and it doesn’t end with neckties, PCs, or big corporations. It’s the unwritten rules, behavior, beliefs, and the motivations that enable good work to get done, or it’s what stifles a workforce. For design to be most effective and for designers to feel valued, we need to work in a culture that embraces design and allows it to succeed.</p>

                <p>In Aaron’s session he will explore how to recognize the traits of organizations that *get* design, both large and small. He will share what those teams, departments, and companies have that others don’t, and more importantly, how to begin to change your own workplace’s culture. Once you’ve worked within a culture of design it’s almost impossible to imagine yourself anywhere else.</p>

                <h4>ABOUT AARON</h4>
                <p>Aaron Irizarry is a Senior Product Designer for Nasdaq OMX, a lover of heavy metal, a foodie, and a master of BBQ arts. You can find some of his thoughts and presentations on the conversation surrounding design over at <a href="discussingdesign.com">discussingdesign.com</a>.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, yes you should change the position to `relative`. Second you set the width to  100% and in combination with `position: absolute` it overlaps the other content. You should set another "col" class or add a width property to the `.speakers-info` below 768px. Here I didn't set the width, just changed position property and added margin to distinct the avatar from the name:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

#middle-2 {
width: auto;
color: #000;
margin: 5% 10%;
display: inline-block;
}

.speakers-1{
  margin: 8% 0;
}

.speakers-text {
  padding: 0 5% 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.speakers-info {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 5% 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.speakers-image {
  height: 130px;
  margin: -66px 0 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

[class*="col-"]{
  float: left;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
  
  .speakers-info{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="middle-2">
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="speakers-1">
            <h2>Aaron Irizarry</h2>
            <h3>DESIGNING A CULTURE OF DESIGN</h3>

            <div class="speakers-info col-3 col-s-12">
                <img class="speakers-image" src="https://jolly-kalam.jpg" alt="pic: aaron-irizarry">
                <p><a href="twitter.com/#">@aaroni</a><br><a href="disdesign.com">discussingdesign.com</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="speakers-text col-7 col-s-12">
                <p>Workplace culture doesn’t start with beanbags, foosball tables, or a beer fridge, and it doesn’t end with neckties, PCs, or big corporations. It’s the unwritten rules, behavior, beliefs, and the motivations that enable good work to get done, or it’s what stifles a workforce. For design to be most effective and for designers to feel valued, we need to work in a culture that embraces design and allows it to succeed.</p>

                <p>In Aaron’s session he will explore how to recognize the traits of organizations that *get* design, both large and small. He will share what those teams, departments, and companies have that others don’t, and more importantly, how to begin to change your own workplace’s culture. Once you’ve worked within a culture of design it’s almost impossible to imagine yourself anywhere else.</p>

                <h4>ABOUT AARON</h4>
                <p>Aaron Irizarry is a Senior Product Designer for Nasdaq OMX, a lover of heavy metal, a foodie, and a master of BBQ arts. You can find some of his thoughts and presentations on the conversation surrounding design over at <a href="discussingdesign.com">discussingdesign.com</a>.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```